# Fastapi server not starting after importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, deployment, fastapi

I want to deploy a tensorflow model to fastapi server but anytime i import tensorflow the server does not start

I installed tensorflow via `pip3 install tensorflow-cpu`

This is what is see in the console

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories:
INFO:     Uvicorn running on 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process using WatchFiles
WARNING:  WatchFiles detected changes in 'main.py'. Reloading...
```

Comment: Also see [Minimal Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of TensorFlow may have conflicts with certain FastAPI dependencies. Try installing a different version of TensorFlow